# Qual a diferença de Window e window

Tags: javascript

Há alguns meses tenho estudado *JavaScript* e agora que percebi que tem dois objetos "iguais": o `Window` e o `window`.

Por que existem os dois e qual a diferença entre eles?

**Edição:**
Na verdade vi que o Window é uma *function* e não objeto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Window é o construtor, por isso ele é visto como função, se você digitar

```
window instanceof Window
```

Irá retornar true, já window é a variavel global que é o mesmo que o this do escopo global teste no console do navegador

```
window === this
```

Vai ver que retornará true também, sendo mais especifico window é a instancia de Window, vale ressaltar que você não pode fazer new Window() e sim Window.open, então caso você tenha uma variavel global declarada com um *var* e no escopo global, se você ir no console e digitar window.nomeDaVariavel será possivel acessa-la, o mesmo com o this.